# time limit exceeded in binary search leetcode problem

Tags: java, binary-search

https://leetcode.com/problems/guess-number-higher-or-lower/
above is the link of problem

```
public class Solution extends GuessGame {
public int guessNumber(int n) {
    int start=1;
    int end=n;
    int pick=0;
    while(start<=end){
        int mid=start+(end-start)/2;
        if(guess(mid)==-1){
            end=mid-1;
        }else if(guess(mid)==1){
            start=mid+1;
        }else if(guess(mid)==0) {
            pick=mid;
        }
    }
    return pick;
}
```

}

this code takes more than 500 ms to execute
please suggest why it takes so much time

Comment: Because once you've guessed correctly, you don't exit the loop.  I'd suggest moving `return pick;` up a couple of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply return the value once you get *(guess(mid)==0)* ?
In your case you keep iterating even after your work is done. So you can guess why it takes more time.

So, instead of this --

```
else if(guess(mid)==0)
        pick=mid;
```

use this --

```
else if (guess(mid) == 0) {
        return mid;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It takes 0ms.

```
public class Solution extends GuessGame {
public int guessNumber(int n) {
int start = 1;
int end = n;

while(start<=end){
    
    int mid = start + (end-start)/2;
    
    if(guess(mid)==-1){
        end = mid - 1;
        
    } else if(guess(mid)==1){
        start = mid + 1;
    } else{
        return mid;
    }
    
  }

   return end; 
 }

}
```

At line 13 -> } else if(guess(mid)==0) { <- simply return the mid if your value has been achieved. You are iterating and storing it in pick again and again. You're in a loooooop.

Comment: It's preferred to put explanation before code solution, also you can get rid of 'Guess what .. ' sentence.